# Why is my model having so much ram consumption and taking so long?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, lightgbm

I'm running a model in Kaggle's CareerCon 2019 - Help Navigate Robots competition that is multiclass with 8 classes and I realize that running the model with LGBM and RandomizedSearchCV takes a long time and uses all the available ram (16 GB).

I trained a simple model with LGBM withou hyperparameter tunning and the ram usage didn't explode and ran in about 1 hour.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and what can I do to reduce processing time and ram usage?

Here is a code snippet of the model with hyperparameter tuning:

```
# Use test subset for early stopping criterion
# This allows us to avoid overtraining and we do not need to optimise the number of trees
fit_params={
            'eval_set' : [(x_test, y_test)],
            'eval_names': ['valid'],
            'eval_metric' : 'auc_mu', 
            'callbacks': [lgb.early_stopping(stopping_rounds=30),
                          lgb.log_evaluation(100)]
            }

# Set up HyperParameter search
# We use random search, which is more flexible and more efficient than a grid search
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(3, 50, num = 4)]
max_depth.append(-1)

param_test ={
             'num_leaves': sp_randint(20, 3000),
             'max_depth': max_depth,
             'min_data_in_leaf': sp_randint(0, 3000),
             'learning_rate': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
             'min_child_samples': sp_randint(100, 500), 
             'min_child_weight': [1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4],
             'subsample': sp_uniform(loc=0.2, scale=0.8), 
             'colsample_bytree': sp_uniform(loc=0.4, scale=0.6)
            }

#This parameter defines the number of HP points to be tested
n_HP_points_to_test = 10

#n_estimators is set to a "large value". The actual number of trees build will depend on early stopping and 5000 define only the absolute maximum
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(
    objective = 'multiclass',
    num_class = 8,
    random_state=212,
    verbose=-1,
    metric='auc_mu',
#     n_jobs=-1,
#     device='gpu',
    n_estimators=5000)
gs = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=clf,
    param_distributions=param_test, 
    n_iter=n_HP_points_to_test,
#     scoring='roc_auc',
    cv=3,
#     refit=True,
    n_jobs=-1,
    random_state=212,
    verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `n_jobs = -1` in [`sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) tells `sklearn` that it can use all available CPUs. If you have multiple available CPUs, that means `RandomizedSearchCV` will conduct multiple trials (training runs with different sets of parameters) at the same time.

Each call to `lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.fit(X, y)` creates a [`lightgbm.Dataset`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.2/pythonapi/lightgbm.Dataset.html#lightgbm.Dataset) object, which is an alternative representation of the `numpy` or `pandas` input data `X` and `y`. That `Dataset` consumes less memory than `X` and `y`, but still a notable amount of memory.

`lightgbm` also has its own parallelization mechanism, multi-threading using OpenMP, which results in LightGBM evaluating multiple candidate splits at the same time during tree building **for one training run**. As of `lightgbm` v3.3.2 (the latest published release), its default behavior is to use the number of threads OpenMP is configured to use by default, which on your system might be more than 1.

Taken together, the settings from the original post might lead to significantly higher memory usage because multiple `lightgbm.Dataset` objects may be in memory at the same time.

They might lead to slower training per model compared to a single call to `lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.fit()` because multiple concurrent training processes are each using multiple threads, possibly meaning that more threads are being used than available CPUs, which can lead to contention that causes threads to get stuck waiting for work from other threads to be done.

Given this, you have several options that could be used to evaluate the same set of potential hyper-parameters in less time and/or with lower peak memory usage:

- use `RandomizedSearchCV(n_jobs=1)` and `LGBMClassifier(n_jobs=-1)`

  - or at least ensure that `{n_jobs passed to RandomizedSearchCV} * {n_jobs passed to LGBMClassifier}` is not greater than the number of available CPUs
- construct a `lightgbm.Dataset` yourself, use `del` to remove the training dataset from memory, then use [`lightgbm.cv()`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.2/pythonapi/lightgbm.cv.html) to evaluate LightGBM's performance with each given set of hyperparameters
- reduce the maximum searched value of `num_leaves`
- increase the minimum searched value of `min_data_in_leaf`
- follow the other recommendations in LightGBM's documentation under ["For Faster Speed"](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.2/Parameters-Tuning.html#for-faster-speed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tested just setting RandomizedSearchCV(n_jobs=1) and LGBMClassifier(n_jobs=-1) but it still takes a long time. But I already noticed that it reduced the RAM usage a lot. I see that he spends a lot of time printing the earling_stop logs. With that I was in doubt: does reducing stopping_rounds help in decreasing processing time?
For num_leaves and min_data_in_leaf, do you have a method of estimating the best values ​​for maximum and minimum respectively?